# Inherit components from one customized template to another one in Magnolia CMS 5

Tags: templates, inheritance, content-management-system, magnolia

I need to inherit components and areas from one page which has a customized template to another page (child page) whose customized template is different from the parent's. Is this possible? Someone who can help me out with this as I have spent lots of time on this with no success? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as those pages have same area in which component is created, and they live in same hierarchy (the page that needs to inherit is child page of the one from which it would be inheriting) it should be easy. All you have to do is enable the inheritance and set type of inheritance (filtered/all).

Please see more http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Inheritable+components

You might also want to visit http://forum.magnolia-cms.com to discuss your issues w/ other users.